# What does "crop factor" mean on a DSLR?

Tags: dslr, crop-factor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between focal length and crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-the-difference-between-focal-length-and-crop-factor)

I see the term "crop factor" used to describe some DSLRs (for example, the Canon 7D has a 1.6x crop factor).  What does this mean?