# Advice for a mirrorless camera

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

My DSLR camera (with its lenses) got stolen and I want to buy a digital camera: more precisely, a mirrorless camera. I would like to make:

- street photography above all
- head shots, full body shots, panoramic shots, travel shots
- some effects such as panning, light-painting, infrared photo and high-speed photos.

I have a model in mind, but I won't write it here because I understand that's frowned upon. Sensor must be APS-C. Any suggestions how could I make up my mind about which camera to buy? It would be ok to spend more on the body and buy only lens for now, postponing the purchase of the second one to a later time.

Also, it's been many, many years since I last bought a camera, so any advice on which lens to buy together with the body would be appreciated. Again, I understand you cannot recommend a specific set, but suggestions such as focal lenght, f-ratio, etc. would be great.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure whether my question is an exact duplicate of the mentioned question, because I specified the applications: the other question is more open-ended (it's about "my first mirrorless camera", but I'm specifically looking for a street-photograpy camera, APS-C, capable of high-speed photos, so maybe that translates on some requirements on the lens? or only the motor?).

Comment: In general, shopping questions are [off-topic for the whole of StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), because answers are likely to be time-sensitive (models change every year), opinion-based, and only good for you, not a wider audience. Better to state questions as specific problems you want to solve. Like, say, ["What is a good focal length for street photography?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59932). Or ask the folks at Amazon-owned [dpreview](https://www.dpreview.com/forums). They're happy to help you spend your money.

Comment: I think as it stands, this question is still too broad, because it includes several very disparate use-cases. I think it'd be much better to ask each specifically, even if that results in three questions. Then you can consider each and weigh how much each factor matters to you personally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question that other people cannot really answer for you. I'd recommend making a list of what kinds of characteristics of a camera are important to **you**. So, for example, you say you'd like to use it for street photography. What features do you personally want on your camera, in order to be able to use the camera as you like?

Is there a specific kinds of lens you'd like to use for your street photography? I see you ask about focal length, but street photography can be made from all sorts of focal lenths. The difference is a photographer's style in they approach people and the intended photograph. For example, Cartier-Bresson used a 50mm lens https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Cartier-Bresson#Technique. I like them, too: basic, light, often good quality-for-money... and requiring that one engages with one subject.

Same for the other types of photography you mentioned (as they are pretty diverse).

If you find it hard to make a list of characteristics, I'd recommend looking at broad reviews, comparisons of 5 or 10 different cameras (with lenses) with same images. In print, if possible, as images on screen can be very different. This might help orient you to what kinds of things are mentioned in the photos you think are the kind you'd like to make.

It is not the gear that makes a photograph (although bad gear can 'break' a photograph): it is the user's ability to make the tool do what they want.

Comment: Ah, you suggest a fixed focal lens: this makes sense, as does the rest of your answer. You suggest looking at reviews in print: are you referring to books, or to the specialized press? Shops in my hometown are definitely not going to show me  different pictures from different cameras. Otherwise, are there any websites you would suggest browsing?

Comment: I don't think that was a "recommendation". Perhaps you should start with what lenses and focal lengths you liked using when you had a DSLR?

Comment: @xiota sorry, what is not a recommendation? Concerning lenses, sure, I could just  buy two zooms with the same focal length and aperture of those I used before (maybe one, for starters...mirrorless don't seem a cheap buy). However, I thought to ask: maybe you experts would have suggested different lenses.

Comment: Street - either a 24mm or 35mm if you want a prime.  Which one depends upon your personal preference.  Headshots: a portrait lens around 135mm-200mm. Full-body: 35-50mm.  Pano: ultra-wide zoom like a 10-20. Travel: Utlra-wide & telephoto zoom combo.     Panning and light painting is a technique that can be used with any camera.  Ifrared requires alteration to the camera.  Highspeed requires fast shutter speeds or the use of a flash - any mirrorless or DSLR will do that.

Comment: @DeltaIV yes, I did mean reviews in magazines, photography or consumer press. And Xiota is right, that what I might like, and what Cartier-Bresson used, may not be what suits you or any other photographer. Good luck with it!