# What adapter can I use to fit vintage lenses to a Canon DSLR?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, old-lenses, minolta

I have a Canon 7D and a very modest budget.  I have three lens and am wanting to find an adapter for each to fit on my 7D.

1. Promaster Spectrum 7 28-70mm 1:2.8-4.5 MC Zoom Macro
2. M C Minolta Celtic 1:4.5 f=200mm
3. Ozunon MC Auto Zoom 1:3.5-4.8 35-70mm

I have searched the internet all day (again) and can't seem to find an adapter that will work and possibly wouldn't know it if I saw it.                      I would also be interested in using any of these with a reverse ring for macro photography.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: To figure this out, you have to [identify the lens mount system](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html) the lenses belong to. 3rd party lenses are often made in multiple mounts.

Comment: From the names, I assume that these lenses are [Minolta MC](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/55902/difference-between-minolta-mc-and-md-mounts-and-can-they-be-used-on-af-camera) mount.

Comment: @mattdm Um... MC also often means "multi-coated", and I actually googled up [Canon FD/FL? mount lens on e-bay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/PROMASTER-Spectrum-7-28-70mm-MACRO-ZOOM-Lens-for-CANON-camera-/110901205298) under the first name.

Comment: @inkista Yeah, but the others seem pretty clear.

Comment: @mattdm Second one, yes, but third one, googling landed me on [a Pentax forum](http://www.pentaxforums.com/userreviews/ozunon-35-75mm-f3-5-4-8-mc-auto-zoom.html). :) Up to you. If you change the title back, I'll leave it alone.

Comment: @inkista Okay fair enough

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Premium-Grade-Gaffer-Power%C2%AE/dp/B00GZE3UJ8

Answer (score 2):

**Mount adapting**

It all depends on the mount system(s) of the lenses.  If you know what camera they went on when you bought them, that can help you get there, otherwise, you may have to try and resort to more difficult means, like [this visual guide to dSLR lens mounts](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html).

The six mounts that can easily be adapted to Canon dSLRs with simple adapter rings are:

- Leica R
- Nikon F
- Contax/Yashica
- Olympus OM
- M42 (aka Pentax thread/screw mount)
- Pentax K

Note how Canon FD/FL or Minolta MD/MC are **not** on that list. Other SLR mounts are liable to have a smaller registration distance than Canon EOS mount, and will require an optical element in the adapter to act like a short teleconverter, which will compromise image quality to a certain degree.

Be aware you won't have nearly the same features/function as with a native-mount current lens. No autofocus, no wide-open metering, no modes that require the camera to adjust the aperture of the lens, no lens EXIF, etc. See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000)).

**Macro reversal rings**

With macro reversal rings, it's much easier.  Because you're mounting the lens backwards by its filter threads, you just need to know the individual filter sizes of the lenses, and then get the appropriate sized male-to-male rings (if you're reversing the lens by mounting it face-to-face on another lens). Or you can get a reverse-mount ring (EOS mount on one side, filter threads on the other), and then appropriate step-up/step-down rings to get everything to fit.

To find the filter size, look on the front of the ring for the diameter symbol (⌀), and the size next to it is the filter size of the lens (e.g., "⌀67" means the lens takes a 67mm filter).

Comment: Suggest mentioning that *for the purposes of macro photography*, mounting Canon FD/FL or Minolta MD/MC lenses on the EOS body would be no problem. Because of the shorter registration distance (and without the refocusing adapter you mentioned), the lenses would lose the ability to focus at infinity. In essence, this lens/body combo acts like a macro-with-extension-tube configuration. I don't know if adapter rings without the refocusing element are available, though...

Comment: @scottbb, felt I didn't need to completely duplicate my answer on the lens X/camera Y questions, and it's mentioned there.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't fully read your linked answer until after I commented. And to be fair, your linked answer *is* quite lengthy. =)  I probably wouldn't have commented except for the fact that the OP was specifically interested in lens reversing, so I figure the mention that those lenses could get at least *some* use was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

New here. I have 2 Canon manual F-1s with FD lenses. I found an adapter at B&H Photo/Video in NYC. Since then there have been 2 or 3 others for this lens mount to appear.

The lenses have a difficult time focusing at infinity. The sales rep told me this before I purchased the adapter. They have another adapter that is supposed to indicate focus.

These adapters are under $50. I have been satisfied for the most part with the performance of the lenses except for that caveat.

Canon Rebel T3

Cheers!

Comment: Hello kdd, welcome to photo.se. Could you be more specific regarding your FD lens and the adaptor you used to mount them on your Rebel T3 ? What is the maximum distance you can focus at ?

Comment: 35-105mm f3.5, 28mm f2.8, 200mm f2.8

Comment: On phone will reply later. Sorry.

Comment: You should [edit] your existing answer rather than posting a new answer, *unless* you are proposing a separate solution to the OP's problem in which case it can *sometimes* be a good idea to post multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Vello FD to EOS adapter.

As far as maximum focusing distance for each lens, I dont have a clue. I just don't focus to infinity. I let my DoF setting take care of infinity.

I use Hyperdistance focusing with the FD lenses. On the lens barrel in front of the aperture ring is a set of f numbers on either side of the critical focus mark. I set the infinity mark on the chosen f number I use, usually f22 depending on the lens, and read the minimum focus distance on the other side of the mark at the chosen f number. I know that everything from the minimum distance to infinity will be in focus. It helps to use a tripod when you use this method.