# How Focal Lengths is  related to Sensor Size?

Tags: lens, sensor, cropped-sensor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between focal length and crop factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-the-difference-between-focal-length-and-crop-factor)

I was watching a video review of Tamron 70-300 lens where he mentioned that effective Focal length for a full frame sensor at max zoom is 300 but for APSc sensor it will be 480, How is that it differs based on Sensor size ?

Comment: Thanks ! that clears a lot, I didnt know the actual terms so question might have been duplicated.