# What does "focal length multiplier" mean?

Tags: focal-length, crop-factor

I have heard of something called a focal length multiplier, particularly in connection with the size of the image sensor in a camera.  What I don't understand is what this is and why ans how it is related to the size of the sensor.  Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Focal length multiplier" is another term for "crop factor". It is used for comparing the angle of view of a lens of a given focal length across film or sensor size.

This is explained in more detail at

[What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-the-relationship-between-focal-length-and-crop-factor)

and the relationship between focal length, sensor size, and angle of view is explained at [What is "angle of view" in photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5917/what-is-angle-of-view-in-photography/5924#5924)

Comment: and it's even more of a misnomer in that the focal length does not get multiplied at all.