# With Autopano Giga, should I multiply the focal length by the crop factor?

Tags: panorama, cropped-sensor, samyang

Guys I have a Canon 7D aps-c with 1.6x crop,
and I have a Samyang 8mm for Canon cameras.

Here is my question.
As the lens does not have electronic contacts on it to connect to the camera, there is no EXIF data. When I wanna use programs like PTGui, it asks me for the focal length and multiplier, which I assume is 8 mm and 1.6.
But what about the other programs like Autopano Giga??
In APG you can only define the focal length.
So shall I write the 8 mm or shall I multiply the 8mm by 1.6 and then the result would be my actual focal length?

Comment: Why not try both and see what happens?

Comment: Also, although it seems counterintuitive, you'll probably have better luck using longer focal length lenses that demonstrate less geometric distortion. Of course you'll also need to take more shots.

Comment: My question is more about the photography knowledge behind of it

Comment: But yes of course i can try both to see what will happend, oh by the way, lenses with less distortion, means many many more pictures than just 8-20 what usually needed for a full 360 degree panorama, and not to forget, if you have fisheye lens like this, u wont really need a pano head tripod and rotator and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their documentation](http://www.kolor.com/wiki-en/action/view/Autopano_-_Main_Window_-_Image_Properties), **use 8mm, the actual focal length of the lens.**  Autopano uses the camera model information from the camera EXIF to determine your crop factor, and will calculate the 35mm-film equivalency of your lens automatically.

Also, your *actual* focal length is always what's printed on the front of the lens. The focal length of a lens is a physical property that does not change just because you change the size of the sensor behind it. Equivalency is really only about field of view. See: [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139)