# Difference between photo mode vs video mode on iPhone

Tags: macro, iphone, smartphone

I take 2 images with the same position.

Photo mode:
[image: photo]

Video mode with the flash is on:
[image: video]

Why the image that I get from the video frame is more narrow and not blur than photo mode?

And can I take the image like the Video mode with Photo mode? I tried and I cannot take the image like that in Photo mode, if I move the iPhone closer, it cannot focus on the subject.

Comment: What model iPhone do you have?

Comment: @EricShain I use iPhone 6

Answer (score 2):

One is a straight on single-frame image from the phone. That is the native aspect ratio of the sensor which every pixel gets to contribute to the image.

The second uses a cropped area so that the phone can filter the image to account for motion of the phone which is why a few pixels are lost. By having those extra pixels and motion information, processing can be applied to make the output look sharper.

This is essentially a digital simulation of image stabilization.

Answer (score 1):

It appears though that in video mode, the images are cropped. [Here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86075/does-the-iphones-focal-length-differ-when-taking-video-vs-photos) is a discussion with more in depth explanations than I can ever give. I hope it points you in the right direction.