# Why does Lightroom show the focal length of the Sony RX10 IV as 220mm, when it's marketed as 600mm?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, focal-length, sony

I have a Sony RX 10 IV. I used maximum zoom, 600mm, but when editing in Lightroom in the details it gives the focal length of 220mm.

Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139/what-is-crop-factor-and-how-does-it-relate-to-focal-length)

Answer (score 2):

The sensor in the Sony RX10 iv is a one-inch sensor. The "600mm" is actually the "full-frame equivalent" of the 220mm lens you really have. In other words, your 220mm lens produces on your sensor the same framing as a 600mm lens on a bigger (24x36mm) sensor.

If you had a true 600mm lens,

1. the camera would be very heavy (several pounds)
2. it would be barely usable in practice (that would be roughly a 1500mm-equivalent, you would need a very stable tripod to use it).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, your camera doesn't have a 600mm focal length. Sony is lying to you. The Sony RX10 IV has a 8.8-220mm lens. Sony lists it [in the specifications here](https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/cyber-shot-compact-cameras/dsc-rx10m4/specifications). But they've done a very naughty thing by marketing the camera aggressively using incorrect focal lengths.

Focal length is a physical property of a lens. Combined with a sensor of a given size, the angle of view can be determined. But there are lots of different lenses and lots of different sensor sizes, and it can get a bit confusing for some people when equating things, so there is this convention where people talk about *equivalent* focal length of a lens - that is, what focal length lens would produce the same angle of view if used on a 35mm film camera (because people were used to equating a focal length and an angle of view from the days when 35mm film was king).

When your camera is set to maximum zoom (220mm), it captures a photo with the same angle of view that a 35mm film camera would if it had a 600mm lens mounted (because the sensor in your camera is smaller than a frame of 35mm film). So the lens is said to have an *equivalent* focal length of 600mm, and that's what Sony has labelled the camera body with. Lightroom is behaving properly and reporting the real focal length.

Comment: The body is correctly labeled.

Comment: @fkraiem Indeed you are right and I was mistaken. I was referring to the [markings on the lens barrel](https://presscentre.sony.eu/images/rx10-iv-top-tele-eu08-1040926), but I only now saw that it is labelled as "35mm equiv."

Answer (score 0):

It's customary to specify the range of a compact camera as "35mm equivalent".  Your sensor is smaller than that of a "full-frame" 35mm camera (which should have a 36mm×24mm sensor) by a factor of 2.7 I think.  That means that to get photographs with the same framing (outline), you only need 1/2.7 of the actual focal length.  600mm/2.7 is about 220mm.

For a compact camera (non-removable lens), the specifications in display (unless given as a zoom "factor") and on the *side* of the lens barrel will be in full-frame equivalent, as will be the advertisements.  The script on the *front* of the lens will specify the *actual* focal length.

Here is how it looks on a Sony DSC-R1 compact:
[image: DSC-R1 lens]
You can see that the lens is marked on its front with 14.3–71.5 (the true focal length) while the zoom control is marked "Equiv.135" (full-frame equivalent) and goes from 24mm (not depicted) to 120mm.  So the "crop factor" here, the fraction this camera's sensor is compared to a full-frame one, is 120/71.5, about 1.67.

*Detachable* lenses will get marketed with the *actual* focal length (printed on its front) since the sensor size they are used with could theoretically vary a bit.  This usually also holds for "kit lenses" sold together with a camera body.