# What are the equivalent focal lengths for iPhone digital zoom?

Tags: focal-length, iphone, digital-zoom

I would like to know what the equivalent focal lengths are when in digital zoom on an iPhone 13 Max Pro – greater than 3X to 15X.

Comment: I can't answer specifically, but an idea: take some photos and examine the meta data, with most cameras the focal length is listed.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent focal lengths of the three cameras in the iPhone 13 Pro Max are:

- [ultrawide] **13mm** [1/3.4" sensor, 8.18x crop, so really a 1.5mm lens]
- [primary] **26mm** [1/1.65" sensor, 4.46x crop, so really a 5.8mm lens]
- [tele] **77mm** [1/3.4" sensor, 8.18x crop, so really a 9.4mm lens]

I referred to [this dpreview article](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/6780391159/all-apple-iphone-13-and-13-pro-camera-upgrades-explained) for the sensor sizes and equivalent focal lengths; and [this chart](https://designreviews.com/standards/digital-camera-sensor-size-chart/) to help [calculate the crop factors](https://www.adorama.com/alc/what-is-crop-factor-everything-you-need-to-know/).

The optical zoom factors are all calculated *relative to the primary camera*:

- 13mm/26 = **0.5x**
- 26mm/26 = **1x**
- 77m/26 ≅ **3x**

so just take the zoom factor, multiply it by 26mm and you'll get the equivalent FoV focal length. E.g., 15x26mm = 390mm.

But, of course, digital zooming is really just cropping and upscaling, so it's not *really* equivalent to using a different focal length. See also: [What is crop factor and how does it relate to focal length?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/139)