# Software to combine multiple similar photos and choose the best parts from each

Tags: photo-editing, group-photos

*Note: This question was originally posted on [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48719/software-to-combine-multiple-similar-photos-and-choose-the-best-parts-from-each), but due to lack of activity I'm reposting it here.*

Windows Live Gallery had a [great Photo Fuse feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tis_G1loFto) that allowed you to select multiple similar photos and be able to select which faces from each photo would be used in the final composite image. This was great for group photos where in every photo someone isn't looking at the camera or blinking etc, as you can combine them all and select all the faces that are looking.

Unfortunately, Windows Live Gallery is now [unsupported and unavailable for download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18614/windows-essentials). Is there any free software that has similar functionality (offline/online)?

Comment: @Rob Your comment, while short, is actually a complete answer. [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short)

Comment: @scottbb - I was concerned that it was more of a 'link answer' than an answer, and it's untested by me - just what I discovered while looking for a replacement. --- Previously *this* SE site has taken really short answers and converted them to a comment a few minutes later; I'll check back and see if I can delete both these comments tomorrow.

Comment: @Rob I'd love to see examples of too-short answers converted to comments that you're talking about, if you come across them. Usually when answers are converted to comments, it's not because of length; rather, the answer doesn't actually answer anything, and appears to either ask a question of the OP or another answerer, or just makes a, well, _comment_ on something. Generally, I feel that the mods do a good job of screening actual answers from being converted to comments. Regardless, thanks for making an answer. =)

Comment: @scottbb - I'm not sure if you have high enough rep to read deleted comments but the copied answer is here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-exactly-determines-depth-of-field/96275#96275 and my deleted comments with MC's comments here: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/how-does-background-blur-bokeh-relate-to-sensor-size/96261#96261 - I think I answered "See this answer: [shared link]" and it got converted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is built-in with newest [Windows Essentials](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/gallery-program/where-to-download-windows-essentials-2012/7665b354-4f2b-445d-811e-9d8c98e8f872).

This link from 2018 says it still works: http://techizoo.com/windows-photo-gallery/ .

Comment: can you add an example images, like A+B=C? in case link breaks in the future

Comment: Thanks for the link - glad to see I can still download it. I have to admit, I'm still interested to see if there are any current/supported applications with this feature. Surely there must be other software that has this feature apart from Windows Live Gallery...

Comment: @AmrBekhit - I was looking for other software, when I found out that the feature used to be a plugin but was removed because plugins were found to contain a security flaw. Later they added the feature back in, integrally, without using plugins. Apparently it's an advanced algorithm, you might have trouble finding something equal; once I found an answer to your question I discontinued further searching. I do know that there are cellphones that can take multiple shots and pick the best one, add bits and pieces together or remove photobombers; but that's not what you asked for ...

Comment: @Rob: Thanks - I downloaded the software from the link you provided and got the job done. Much appreciated.