# How to shoot with the Brenizer method with an active, moving background, i.e. on the streets

Tags: depth-of-field, shooting-technique, panorama, bokeh, brenizer-method

If the background is moving, like a street full of people and you're shooting a stationary subject with the Brenizer method, how does that work? When you stitch up the surrounding area wouldn't it be all choppy and wrong because by the time you snap the consecutive shot someone or something in the background would have moved?

The second half of the video here is exactly what I'm trying to refer to. The one of the couple in the shot in the middle of a busy street in the city.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/carpeicthus/3117948025/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general trick here is *luck* combined with plenty of frames over a few second timespan and some post processing of the unwanted subjects out.

He shot so many images that he was able to pick and choose the frames with the least amount of background distractions(people). It looks like two shadows even were left behind that he either did not have images without, or did not take the time to remove manually during post processing.

Even the photographer himself was surprised that the shot turned out, and that is why I mention **luck** as an important component here!

> I'm actually amazed the shot came out, but it did, and it looks like they're virtually alone in the square.

I don't see this as being any different from the process described in this answer:

[What is “bokeh panorama” (also called the “Brenizer method”)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/8509/4892)