# How is the term Gaussian blur used?

Tags: post-processing, terminology, focus, bokeh

Is the term Gaussian blur used strictly in post-production, or can it also be used as a term for an out-of-focus area in your image when you-re taking the picture? I'm pretty sure that bokeh is used to describe an area out-of-focus when you're taking the picture, can gaussian blur also be used when you're taking the picture?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this here?:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/whats-the-difference-between-bokeh-and-gaussian-blur

Comment: No. That question was asking what the difference was. This question is asking if gaussian blur can be used to describe an out-of-focus part of an image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not appropriate to use the term "Gaussian blur" for the out-of-focus parts of an image, because "Gaussian" refers to a [specific blurring function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function). It's the same Gaussian curve that you may know from the "normal distribution" or "bell curve" in statistics. A bright point that's smoothed by a Gaussian will taper smoothly from a bright center to a dark edge.

[image: Gaussian Blur]

*Example of bright points with Gaussian Blur, made in the GIMP.*

The out-of-focus parts of your photograph are not smoothed in the same way. Instead, an out-of-focus bright point in your image will appear in the shape of your aperture. So if your lens isn't stopped down, it will look like a bright circle. It doesn't taper smoothly from the center to the edge like a Gaussian does. (If your lens is stopped down, you'll get a polygon instead of a circle—for example, a hexagon if your aperture has 6 blades. But the same point applies: It doesn't smoothly taper from bright to dark like a Gaussian does.)

[image: Out of focus Sheetz gas station by me]

*In the above picture, notice that the out-of-focus lights are evenly filled circles, not Gaussian profiles (which would fade gradually from a bright center to a dark edge).*

Comment: Depending on over- or under-correction of spherical aberration, out of focus highlights *might* happen to fit a Gaussian profile, but if it's even close to perfectly corrected, they won't. DC Nikkors and the Minolta/Sony STF lens can also produce something closer to a Gaussian profile (in the DC Nikkors' case by letting you adjust spherical aberration correction).

Answer (score 4):

Gaussian blur is a transformation that you apply to (pixels of) your digital image. You can infer that it is an algorithm since the name "Gaussian" refers to the [mathematical properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) of the transformation that you are applying to your image (which is related to the gaussian density exp(-r^2/2).

[Bokeh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/what-is-bokeh-exactly) is the shape of out of focus source of light, depending on the mechanical features of your camera.

As you can see, the two are completely different things.