# How to take bokeh photo with nikon coolpix s6300

Tags: bokeh, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to take shallow depth of field photos with point-and-shoot cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19/is-it-possible-to-take-shallow-depth-of-field-photos-with-point-and-shoot-camera)

I have just bought Nikon Coolpix S6300. I want to take bokeh photograph. So, please tell me how can I set my camera to take bokeh photograph. I don't want to use any software to create bokeh photograph.

Answer (score 3):

Its difficult to get good blurred backgrounds and bokeh with point and shoot cameras like the Coolpix S6300 due to their small sensors.
You may consider switching to a point and shoot with a larger sensor and good quality lens like the Sony RX100, or even better, switching to a interchangeable lens camera like a DSLR or a MILC. Prices of entry-level DSLRs and MILCs have dropped considerably and cost as much as high-end point and shoot models. You can consider models like Nikon D3100, Nikon J1, Sony NEX-C3, Olympus PEN E-PL1 etc.

With your current camera, it will be difficult to get this done.
At best, you can try this - switch to macro mode, go close to your subject (physically), keep the background at a considerable distance, focus and shoot.