# I have a Fujifilm HS25 EXR and its minimun aperture is F2.8. Is there a way of getting a lower aperture for my camera?

Tags: aperture, bokeh, fujifilm

I have a Fujifilm HS25 EXR and its minimum aperture is F2.8, but I want it to be F1.8 (my dream is to achieve the bokeh effect) Is there a way of getting a lower aperture for my camera; maybe a lens or something like that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way to use a conversion lens to make the aperture faster is if you can put it *between* the lens and the sensor. But of course you can't do that with a fixed-lens camera. But take a look at [How can I take shallow depth of field photos with a point-and-shoot camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-can-i-take-shallow-depth-of-field-photos-with-a-point-and-shoot-camera) to see what you *can* do. If that isn't enough, you will need to buy a camera with a larger sensor and faster lens.

Answer (score 0):

The aperture can not be any bigger (faster) than the smallest opening through which the light passes.  No matter what you put on the lens, you can't remove the opening through which the light must pass, so there is no way to change it.