# In video mode, why does adjusting the aperture change the brightness instead of the DoF?

Tags: movie

Currently I'm playing with the LiveView and movie making mode of my D3200 and I'm stuck with a few technical issues.

I can change the shutter speed and the aperture during filming and it has an impact on the brightness of the clip.

But does changing the shutter speed make sense? I mean when you're recording a movie, the lens should be open all the time and when I change aperture it should have an effect on the DoF - but it changes the brightness but not the DoF.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how a question about the effects of shutter speed and aperture **aren't** "relevant to still photography"...

Comment: Inkista - Your own answer proves the point. You stated "The duration of the shutter speed can affect how "choppy" the final video feels, depending on the amount of motion blur in individual frames.". Individual frames are not "choppy" nor do they have a "final video feel". Those aspects are not applicable to still photography and thus not on topic.

Comment: @dpollitt But the *majority* of the question is rooted in not understanding the effects of shutter speed and aperture--concepts which apply to both video and still images. I'm just saying, just because the word "video" appears in a question, doesn't necessarily mean it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Video mode is essentially taking a series of still images, so each image does have a specific shutter speed, and while your mechanical shutter is open all the time, the *electronic* shutter will still be going on and off.  The duration of the shutter speed can affect how "choppy" the final video feels, depending on the amount of motion blur in individual frames. It is also (along with ISO) how you can compensate for brightness from the aperture:

See: [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)

Aperture will *always* affect brightness--the larger the opening, the more light enters the camera, and the brighter the exposure.  Aperture, however, is only one of several factors that determines DoF, and a change in aperture may not actually register as a change in depth of field, depending on those other factors: subject-to-camera distance, subject-to-background distance, and focal length also play a very large role in how much background blur you're going to see.  At certain subject distance and focal length combinations, you may not be able to perceive a difference in depth of field with a simple aperture setting change, particularly at the smaller apertures, lower focal lengths, and longer subject distances.

See: [How can I maximize the "blurry background, sharp subject" (bokeh) effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-i-maximize-the-blurry-background-sharp-subject-bokeh-effect)

Comment: very good explanation ty!